# Javascript php onclick

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hey guys im trying to make a javscript function that will execute php code. This is what I have that should work I think.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit()
{

  $.get("dumplings.php");
    return false; } 



</script>
```

Dumplings.php contains this

```
<?php 
$format = '<OBJECT style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:44%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="rice" ALIGN="">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#333399> <EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#333399 WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>';
echo $format;
?>
```

Here is my radio button:

```
<input name="sample_check3" id="sample_check3" value="1" type="radio" onclick="doit();"/>
```

Basically, it just does nothing. Any idea why its not working?

Comment: Fire up your browser's Developer Console / Firebug and look what errors you get

Comment: What is it supposed to do? `Dumplings.php` returns a string, but I can't see that you're doing anything with the return value in `doit()`.

Comment: [Debug and explore AJAX with FireBug](http://encosia.com/debug-and-explore-aspnet-ajax-with-firebug/)

Answer (score 2):

it propbably does something but when you fetch your page with the php code you do nothing with the result

try changing it to something like this

```
$.get("dumplings.php", function (data){
  $('body').append(data);
});
```

the data will contain the data from your php page. In this example I just add it to the body. but you can do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use $.get on a one of your's page element (

> `<span>,<div>,<p>`

)
After radiobutton add

```
<div id="loadobjecthere"></div>
```

And change script to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit()
{    
  $("#loadobjecthere").get("dumplings.php");
    return false;
}    
</script>
```

Also try to change onclick attribute to

```
"javascript:return doit();"
```